# Can Ethereum wallets be deleted for fraud?

Tags: wallets, security, addresses

Stellar Foundation, who created the Stellar Lumens coin (XLM), are able to shut down XLM addresses that engage in fraud. Stellar scammers often send small payments to other XLM wallets at random with a memo to visit a scam site.

Can Vitalik and Ethereum do the same to ETH wallets: close fraudulent accounts?

Answer (score 2):

The owner of a specific token can maintain a "blacklist" in the context of his token's contract. In relation to the whole Ethereum, the implementation of this is unlikely, if only due to the absence of a owner from the public Ephereum.

Comment: what do you mean by absence of an owner?

Comment: There is no one who clearly owns the public Ethereum and serves as its institutional regulator. In private clones of Ethereum and private platforms created on their basis, account blocking mechanisms are quite successfully implemented.

Comment: by "private clones of Ethereum", you mean ERC20 tokens like Chainlink and UNI (regardless if they implement blocking mechanisms)?

Comment: No, I mean private networks built on the protocol and using Ethereum software, original or modified (geth, for example). For example, cross-company trade finance networks, digital asset networks and the like. They are in no way connected with the public Ethereum.

Comment: by Ethereum software do you mean solidity

Comment: By Ethereum software, I mean programs that implement the Ethereum protocol - for example, **geth**, **parity** and so on, Solidity is essentially a part of the Ethereum protocol.

Answer (score -3):

Actually Ethereum Wallet can not be deleted but yes the owner or admin of the wallet can maintain his blacklist of his tokens contracts. Indefinite access to the [Mastodon](https://mastodons.io/) project is an intrinsic feature programmed into the smart contract to enable continued participation in the matrix project.